# how to get only updated data in solrcore from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am using Solr for full text search and i am successfully index data in Solr core from MongoDB.

But after indexing any data is update in MongoDB for getting that updated data in Solr core i need to use full import any alternative to get only the updated data.

Comment: How are you indexing your data now? `mongo-connector` should do this for you automagically.

Comment: for mongo-connector implementation, I need to convert my DB in replicas. I am using the data-import-handler for that